# Python: difficulty converting ascii to unicode

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

My goal: get the page source from a url and count all instances of a keyword within that page source

How I am doing it: getting the pagesource via urllib2, looping through each char of the page source and comparing it to the keyword

My problem: my keyword is encoded in utf-8 while the page source is in ascii... I am running into errors whenever I try conversions.

getting the page source:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen(myUrl)
return response.read()
```

comparing page source and keyword:

```
pageSource[i] == keyWord[j]
```

I need to convert one of these strings to the other's encoding. Intuitively I felt that ascii (the page source) to utf-8 (the key word) would be the best and easiest, so:

```
    pageSource = unicode(pageSource)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte __ in position __: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use decode('utf-8') and encode('utf-8')?

Comment: Are you sure your page source is ASCII? ASCII is now a subset of UTF-8. I.e. A in ASCII is `0x41`, which is the same as UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume your remote "source page" contains more than just ASCII otherwise your comparison will already work as is (ASCII is now a subset of UTF-8. I.e. A in ASCII is 0x41, which is the same as UTF-8).

You may find Python [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/%20Requests) library easier as it will automatically decode remote content to Unicode strings based on the server's headers (Unicode strings are encoding neutral so can be compared without worrying about encoding).

```
resp = requests.get("http://www.example.com/utf8page.html")
resp.text
>> u'My unicode data €'
```

You will then need to decode your reference data:

```
keyWord[j] = "€".decode("UTF-8")
keyWord[j]
>> u'€'
```

If you're embedding non-ASCII in your source code, you need to define the encoding you're using. For example, at the top of your source code/script:

```
# coding=UTF-8
```

Comment: this library is much better than urllib, thanks for suggesting it! for me, this solution worked

Answer (score 2):

When trying to work with text, don't leave your data as byte strings. Decode to Unicode early, encode back to bytes as late as possible.

Decode your downloaded network data:

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen(myUrl)
# Latin-1 is the default for HTTP text/ responses, adjust as needed
codec = response.info().getparam('charset', 'latin1')
return response.read().decode(codec)
```

and do the same for your `keyWord` data. If it is encoded as UTF-8, decode it as such, or use Unicode string literals.

You may want to read up on Python and Unicode:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)